# Anyone using JAMB (Just Another Map Book) on ArcGIS10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-9.3

I wanted to experiment with [JAMB](http://www.mvn.usace.army.mil/eng/edsd/software/jamb.asp) for creating Plan and Profile figures that our company currently produces in AutoCAD.  I'm having trouble installing JAMB on ArcGIS10, probably because it has not been updated yet, and the jury is still out as to whether it will be.  One of the options I'm looking at is installing [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VirtualBox) and running 9.3.1 side by side with 10.  I contacted ESRI support and they assured me that 9.3.1 can check out 10 licenses, so that looks like a viable option. However it would be easier if JAMB could run on ArcGIS 10.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Well this issue has come up again for us.  We need the ability to generate plan and profile drawings in data driven pages and still haven't found a reasonable solution.  We are on a tight timeline for our project so we don't have time to trouble shoot the JAMB extension running on a virtual PC version of 9.3.1.  Anyone have any 3rd party solutions that might work with ArcGIS 10.1?

Answer (score 1):

I have never used JAMB but Matt Wilkie (who I'm pretty sure maintains the DSMapbook extension, which JAMB appears to be based on) has said that it should be possible to install DSMapbook on Arc 10, though he hasn't tried it:

http://groups.google.com/group/arcmapbook/browse_thread/thread/7248cec90580c3d

Have you looked at ArcGIS 10's Data Driven Pages feature? It's the replacement for DSMapbook, though it doesn't do everything DSMapbook did.

Comment: Thanks for the response Dan.  I ended up installing [Windows Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) so that I could run 9.3.1 on the same machine as ArcGIS 10.  I still haven't had much time to get into JAMB, but I have had a bit of experience with Data Driven Pages, which are very easy to use.  The thing I haven't figured out is how to do a overview plan on the top half of the page and profile view on the bottom half of the page in DD Pages.  Maybe once I get more into JAMB it will make sense.